# Spring Boot profile properties doesn't work with tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, integration-testing

Spring Boot version 2.2.6. I have case that there is several `application-{profile}.yml` files in folder `src/main/resources/` and I want't to build project with Maven e.g `mvn clean package -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`

Then I have just `application.yml` file in folder `src/test/resources`, this should be a properties file to all test (IT/unit).

Now when I build with command `mvn clean package -Dspring.profiles.active=dev`, properties `src/main/resources/application-dev.yml` and `src/test/resources/application.yml` are MERGED and used for the tests. Well in test properties there might be pretty fatal confs e.g Hibernate auto-ddl: create-drop.

Have been reading docs but I don't find any logic why properties files are MERGED in this case. Is there any good practice that tests can be forced to use ALWAYS certain properties file? I think that just using some annotations in test files isn't the best practice, e.g `@TestPropertySource` or `@ActiveProfiles`, cause when you forgot to use these annotations then the case is same again. Is there some global configuration for all tests or some other better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The `application.yml` file has higher precedence over any environment-specific file, for example, `application-dev.yml` file. The standard inheritance applies, so you can override the parent properties in the profile-specific YAML file.

**`application.yml`**

```yaml
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
```

**`application-dev.yml`**

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

In case you run with the `dev` profile, the value of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` parameter would be `none`.

Answer (score 0):

I get that application.yml has higher precedence in folder /src/main, but that it takes over also from folder /src/test is kinda weird.

Yes that config can be made into profile-specific files (ddl-auto: none), tough I still have problem with datasource, somehow Spring Boot is picking application-dev.ymls datasource into tests also, this is working like other way around than that ddl-auto attribute.

**`src/test/resources/application.yml`**

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=PostgreSQL
```

**`src/main/resources/application-dev.yml`**

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
```